# How do I download and save an inbuilt library from R in my desktop as a .Rdata file?

Tags: r

everyone! I am kinda new to R and was trying to download the Women data from the inbuilt Data set library in R. I understand that I have to use the save function to do so, but i am uncertain how.

Comment: Do you just mean something like `save(women, file = "women.Rdata")`? What exactly did you try? What isn't working?

Comment: What format did you want to download it to? CSV? R type storage? Or are you just trying to use the data in R?

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
write.csv(x = data("women"), file = "women.csv")
```

will save the `women.csv` in your working directory. You can check location by running `getwd()` or specify path using the `file` argument.